# Text field generated instead of numeric

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

Given a model with a property defined as

```
[Display(Name = nameof(Amount), ResourceType = typeof(Resources.ViewModels.MyViewModel))]
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Generic))]
[Range(0.1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceName = "AboveZero", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Generic))]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

Used in a view as:

```
<input id="amount" asp-for="Amount" class="form-control" />
```

Generates `<input type="text" ...>`

If I add `type="number"` it correctly generates a number field. Is this a bug or decimal is treated differently and if so why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. Asp.net Core maps decimal type to text field:
See [InputTagHelper.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/ada42ea913097f31bcbe495cf48879bfa9c5efe9/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/InputTagHelper.cs)

```
 private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _defaultInputTypes =
        new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        {
            { "HiddenInput", InputType.Hidden.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() },
            { "Password", InputType.Password.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() },
            { "Text", InputType.Text.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() },
            { "PhoneNumber", "tel" },
            { "Url", "url" },
            { "EmailAddress", "email" },
            { "Date", "date" },
            { "DateTime", "datetime" },
            { "DateTime-local", "datetime-local" },
            { "Time", "time" },
            { nameof(Byte), "number" },
            { nameof(SByte), "number" },
            { nameof(Int16), "number" },
            { nameof(UInt16), "number" },
            { nameof(Int32), "number" },
            { nameof(UInt32), "number" },
            { nameof(Int64), "number" },
            { nameof(UInt64), "number" },
            { nameof(Single), InputType.Text.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() },
            { nameof(Double), InputType.Text.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() },
            { nameof(Boolean), InputType.CheckBox.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() },
            { nameof(Decimal), InputType.Text.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() },
            { nameof(String), InputType.Text.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() },
            { nameof(IFormFile), "file" },
            { TemplateRenderer.IEnumerableOfIFormFileName, "file" },
        };
```

Comment: Any reason why?

Comment: There is an inconsistency in browsers how decimal type is treated in the number type field. For example Chrome requires (used to require?) step attribute in order to work with decimal numbers. MVC developers decided to use text type for all decimal type values. See discussion here https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2712